# The best way to import R object into Python?

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know that there is a Python package that imports RData file.

But I was wondering if that is the best option for me.

I have Dataframes in R that I want to use in Python.

I was wondering if I should save this as json or csv and then read with pandas in Python, or I should just save it as RData and use the rpy2 package.

All I need is just turn these R dataframes into Python data frame, so I can manipulate and combine with other results I calculated in Python...

Comment: This seems somewhat opinion based. For generic data frames, the csv route seems both easy and reliable.

Comment: `R -> CSV -> Pandas` I don't see the cause for doubt here.

Comment: csv, tsv, json, any of those will work. You could use `feather` which would do a little more type preservation, though who knows how stable it is. *"What is the best option for me"* is highly subjective, and you offer no criteria for evaluation.

Comment: Thank you guys. You guys are absolutely right. I am using R and Python for Statistics a lot, but I am not really familiar with the computer in general.. like what types of operations will use more resources, or have higher chance of error or etc. And there are so so many packages to try... 

I think I will read about feather, and will probably use either feather or CSV (or json). 

Thank you for the wise answers for my dumb question :))

Comment: @WKW I think that if you are not really familiar with programming then that is a stronger reason to go the simple csv route. csv files are a form understood by R, Pandas, Excel, SAS, ... They are the lingua franca of stats packages.

Comment: All ascii test-based conversion are bound to loose precision, and hence information, as they generally do _not_ print to machine precision.  To use R from Python, consider [RPy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for the comment. I am now half curious and half worried, since the data I am trying to export are the weights, which are usually very small. But I think what you are saying also applies to saving python data for later, using JSON or CVS. Am I correct? Then what is the most precise and universal(between python and R) way to store the data?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel But now I am confused.. Shouldn't it be negligible? I am not calculating something but just storing the data in R and loading it in Python..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`feather`**](https://github.com/wesm/feather).

It's a data format for data frames (created by [**@Wes McKinney**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/776560/wes-mckinney) and [**@hadley**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley)) to make data sharing between `R` and `python` easy (and some other languages too).

In **`R`:**

```
library(feather)
file_path <- "foo.feather"  
data_frame <- read_feather(file_path)    
write_feather(data_frame, file_path)
```

In **`python`:**

```
import feather
file_path = 'foo.feather'
data_frame = feather.read_dataframe(file_path)
feather.write_dataframe(data_frame, file_path)
```

PS.: [Podcast on feather](http://dataskeptic.com/%20feather) where authors discuss it's application, pros/cons and future.

Comment: Is it possible to pass `feather` objects in memory between R and Python?